# UnicodeDecodeError utf-8 can't decode byte

Tags: python, pandas

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames]) is not working showing

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 12: invalid start byte

entire code below:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("S/Last Processed Data")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])

combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: You need to pass the actual encoding of the  file to `encoding` argument of `read_csv`. By default it's `utf-8`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the encoding argument when you are reading the file:

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, encoding=...) for f in all_filenames])
```

If `utf-8` doesn't work, try `ISO-8859-1`.